# I'm stuck in this area. What show I do with this?

Tags: c++, database, string, integer

I am doing this question for C++, and I cannot figure it out right now. What am I doing wrong with this one? Once again, this is in C++, not python.

Capital Quiz

Write a program that creates a map containing the U.S. states as keys, and their capitals as values. (Use the Internet to get a list of the states and their capitals.) The program should then randomly quiz the user by displaying the name of a state and ask the user to enter that state’s capital. The program should keep a count of the number of correct and incorrect responses. (As an alternative to the U.S. states, the program can use the names of countries and their capitals.)

Here's my work so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<string, string> states = {
{"Alabama", "Montgomery"}, {"Alaska", "Juneau"}, {"Arizona", "Phoenix"} {"Arkansas","Little Rock"},
        {"California", "Sacramento"}, {"Colorado", "Denver"}, {"Connecticut", "Hartford"},
        {"Delaware", "Dover"}, {"Florida", "Tallahassee"}, {"Georgia", "Atlanta"}, {"Hawaii", "Honolulu"},
        {"Idaho", "Boise"}, {"Illinois", "Springfield"}, {"Indiana", "Indianapolis"},
        {"Iowa", "Des Moines"}, {"Kansas", "Topeka"}, {"Kentucky", "Frankfort"},
        {"Louisiana", "Baton Rouge"}, {"Maine", "Augusta"}, {"Maryland", "Annapolis"},
        {"Massachusetts", "Boston"}, {"Michigan", "Lansing"}, {"Minnesota", "Saint Paul"},
        {"Mississippi", "Jackson"}, {"Missouri", "Jefferson City"}, {"Montana", "Helena"},
        {"Nebraska", "Lincoln"}, {"Nevada", "Carson City"}, {"New Hampshire", "Concord"},
        {"New Jersey", "Trenton"}, {"New Mexico", "Santa Fe"}, {"New York", "Albany"},
        {"North Carolina", "Raleigh"}, {"North Dakota", "Bismarck"}, {"Ohio", "Columbus"},
        {"Oklahoma", "Oklahoma City"}, {"Oregon", "Salem"}, {"Pennsylvania", "Harrisburg"},
        {"Rhode Island", "Providence"}, {"South Carolina", "Columbia"}, {"South Dakota", "Pierre"},
        {"Tennessee", "Nashville"}, {"Texas", "Austin"}, {"Utah", "Salt Lake City"},
        {"Vermont", "Montpelier"}, {"Virginia", "Richmond"}, {"Washington", "Olympia"},
        {"West Virginia", "Charleston"}, {"Wisconsin", "Madison"}, {"Wyoming", "Cheyenne"}
    };
    
    map<string, string>::iterator it;
    
    for (it = states.begin(); it != states.end(); it++){
        cout << "What is the capital of " << states.first << "?" << endl;
        cout << states.first << " " << states.second << endl;
    };
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No need to reassure it's not python. On the one hand, you didn't tag python. On the other, C++ looks nothing like python. There are probably a few other 'hands' as well. Also, what's your question?

Comment: I only reassured that because there were a lot of posts that I found with this question, and they were all python and not C++. My question was how do I make my program search all over the map to look for a string I typed in.

Comment: I don't really care what your reasons were. The tags and the code make it obvious enough.

Comment: I have doubt about "states.first" and "states.second", they should be "it.first" and "it.second".

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you need a random number generator, a way to receive input/output, a way to access those values.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <random> 
#include <ctime> 
#include <map>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::string> states = {
    {"Alabama", "Montgomery"}, {"Alaska", "Juneau"}, {"Arizona", "Phoenix"}, {"Arkansas","Little Rock"},
        {"California", "Sacramento"}, {"Colorado", "Denver"}, {"Connecticut", "Hartford"},
        {"Delaware", "Dover"}, {"Florida", "Tallahassee"}, {"Georgia", "Atlanta"}, {"Hawaii", "Honolulu"},
        {"Idaho", "Boise"}, {"Illinois", "Springfield"}, {"Indiana", "Indianapolis"},
        {"Iowa", "Des Moines"}, {"Kansas", "Topeka"}, {"Kentucky", "Frankfort"},
        {"Louisiana", "Baton Rouge"}, {"Maine", "Augusta"}, {"Maryland", "Annapolis"},
        {"Massachusetts", "Boston"}, {"Michigan", "Lansing"}, {"Minnesota", "Saint Paul"},
        {"Mississippi", "Jackson"}, {"Missouri", "Jefferson City"}, {"Montana", "Helena"},
        {"Nebraska", "Lincoln"}, {"Nevada", "Carson City"}, {"New Hampshire", "Concord"},
        {"New Jersey", "Trenton"}, {"New Mexico", "Santa Fe"}, {"New York", "Albany"},
        {"North Carolina", "Raleigh"}, {"North Dakota", "Bismarck"}, {"Ohio", "Columbus"},
        {"Oklahoma", "Oklahoma City"}, {"Oregon", "Salem"}, {"Pennsylvania", "Harrisburg"},
        {"Rhode Island", "Providence"}, {"South Carolina", "Columbia"}, {"South Dakota", "Pierre"},
        {"Tennessee", "Nashville"}, {"Texas", "Austin"}, {"Utah", "Salt Lake City"},
        {"Vermont", "Montpelier"}, {"Virginia", "Richmond"}, {"Washington", "Olympia"},
        {"West Virginia", "Charleston"}, {"Wisconsin", "Madison"}, {"Wyoming", "Cheyenne"}
    };
    std::mt19937 mersenne{ static_cast<std::mt19937::result_type>(std::time(nullptr)) };    

    std::uniform_int_distribution<> die{0, (int)states.size() - 1};

    int totalGuess {};
    int correctGuess{};

    while(true)
    {
        int randomNum {die(mersenne)};
        auto iter = std::next(states.begin(), randomNum);

        std::cout << "What is the capital of " << iter->first << "?";
        std::string guess{};
        std::cin >> guess;
        if(guess == iter->second)
        {
            std::cout << "Right\n"; 
            ++correctGuess;
        }
        else
            std::cout << "Wrong\n";
        
        ++totalGuess;
    }
            

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I believe this code seems to make much sense how. I will have to make some adjustments on your code to make it my own, but so far, this clears everything up. I appreciate it.

Comment: @GameFace If my answer is helpful, consider accept my answer